# How to enable RCI in SonarQube 4.3?

Tags: sonarqube

I am doing code anaylysis using SonarQube version 4.3 with Sonar Runner 2.4. But I don't see RCI (Rules compliance index) which was there in version 3.7.

Question:

1. is RCI replaced by Technical Debts ? (as in [SONAR-4820](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4820))
2. is it possible to view RCI in SonarQube version 4.3, if so how ?

Comment: Not sure for 4.3, we use 4.5.6, and it can be shown in dashboard (issue filter) by adding new column RCI. And the corresponding plugin is issue density plugin. You can refer to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Density+Plugin

Answer (score 4):

FYI @goodspeed, we're going to reintroduce this RCI metric by publishing a dedicated plugin. I expect this plugin to be released by the end of July.

Comment: Thanks Freddy. We are currently using Widget Lab plugin to get RCI.

Comment: @Freddy: Any update on this? Eagerly waiting for it.

Answer (score 2):

After searching for some time, I found out that RCI is deprecated from default widget after SonarQube 4.0. Refer the following for more info:
1) http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4755
2) http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonarqube-4-2-Rules-Compliance-Metric-missing-tt5023713.html